# Ruby on Rails - Cloudinary stale request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloudinary

Whilst I have a user upload to `cloudinary` using an `attachinary` gem I receive a message error that says this:

> Stale request - reported time is 2016-12-15 04:14:53 +0000 which is more than 1 hour ago

I have spent days trying to fix this problem. It seems like I'm the only one getting it as I have found no issues related to this.

Has anyone experienced this and if so how do I solve such an issue.

Comment: Generally this error implies that the timestamp provided with the upload request is outdated (at least by 1 hour). As Tal mentioned, this may happen from time to time due to bad timezone or clock configuration on your machine/server. You can try debugging this, by adding printouts to the GEM's source code or follow your outgoing upload requests (via browser's network tab or server's logs).

Answer (score 1):

First, check if your machine's clock is set up properly.

Note that if you generate the signature on page render and keep the page open for more than 1 hour, you'll get this error.